# My homework about algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please help

Find the fraction of

$$\frac{3^{2^{2555}}+3^{2^{2554}}+3^{2^{2553}}+\cdots+3^{2^{2012}}}{2^{941}}$$

Working method show is really appreciate

Thank you

Poom

Comment: Do you know modular arithmetic?

Comment: @Sabyasachi Not really

Comment: Okay, I will attempt a solution using only algebra then.

Comment: Thanks a lot  I really appreciated.

Comment: you already have an answer btw :)

Comment: In what class is this homework?

Comment: I just pass by the test in the book teaxher gave me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Using [Carmichael Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html),

$\displaystyle \lambda(2^n)=2^{n-2}$ for $n\ge3$

$\displaystyle \implies 3^{2^{n-2}}\equiv1\pmod{2^n}$

$\displaystyle \implies3^{2^m}\equiv1\pmod{2^n}$ if $m\ge n-2$

Here the number of terms is numerator is $\displaystyle2555-2012+1$  which is $<< 2^{941}$

Comment: Note that OP has written in the comments that he/she doesn't know modular arithmetic.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, sorry, I missed that, let me delete  this

Comment: No need to delete it --- if it doesn't help OP, it might help someone else.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I really yarn to see solution(s) w/o modular arithmetic

Comment: Considering that it's a question about the remainder upon division, it begs for modular arithmetic. This is why I have asked OP, what class assigns this as homework?

Comment: Thank you very much, this make me learn new things.

Comment: @lab does my answer does the job?

Answer (score 1):

By repeated use of the difference of squares formula, we can see:
$$P=3^{2^{n}}-1=(3-1)\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(3^{2^{i}}+1)$$
Since there are $n$ even terms in the productorial and one outside, $P$ is divisible by $2^{n+1}$.So
$$N=\frac{(3^{2^{2555}}-1)+(3^{2^{2554}}-1)+(3^{2^{2553}}-1)+\cdots+(3^{2^{2012}}-1)}{2^{941}}$$
Is integer. Conclude.

Comment: Thank you but lab bhattachargee provide clearer answer for me, so I hope you don't mind if I choose him to be the correct answer

Comment: No problem, his solution is way simpler than mine, and you met modular arithmetic thanks to it. I just posted this answer totally avoiding modular arithmetic because some people(especially lab in the comments) were interested to see a proof like that.